# Error during importing a mysql database from 5.6.34 to 5.7.x

Tags: mysql, workbench

I am importing a .sql file using MySQL WorkBench but getting an error for syntax. The sql file was obtained from a DB running 5.6.34 and new one is running 5.7.2.09.1. Here is the screenshot of the error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11347: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFINER=`psx360`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */

Comment: Post the lines around `11347` in the .sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the .sql file with your code editor such as vscode, then search and replace (like press `CTRL + H`) `DEFINER=psx360@localhost SQL SECURITY DEFINER` with blank value in the replace textbox. ie deleting all the occurence.

Comment: Used vscode and removed all occurences of that line. When I tried doing the import its giving me this error now.

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11347: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VIEW `delivery_accepted_view` AS (select `meta`.`activity_id` AS `Activity_Id`,`' at line 1

Comment: I'm afraid of telling you to remove the ```meta.``` occurrence because it may be a table name, but mysql usually add database name to view, try scan through all the view you have and remove database name. Like search and replace the database name with ```**.**``` ie if database name is app, then search for ```app.``` and delete all occurrence.

Please, backup your .sql before going ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Getting an error that I need superuser priveleges, but I am logged in as the admin user.

ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 11363: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: if youre using window, install xampp and use console.

after the installation, open window console as administrator and change directory: ```cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin```

then login to mysql console with: ```mysql -u root```

create the database you intend to import into: ```create database dbName;```

then use the database ```use dbName;```, and source your dump sql file in it (the one you've removed the ```definer``` and other errors) : ```source THE_DUMP_SQL_FILE_DIRECTORY.sql``` ie ```source c:\user\desktop\file_name.sql```